# Accessing a JSON array via javascript (that includes a JSON object) that was created with Java on Android

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, json, object

I am trying to communicate from Java->JS in Android through the use of JSON. I currently create the JSON like so in Java:

```
JSONObject latLng = new JSONObject();
latLng.put("lat",20.000);
latLng.put("lon",20.000);

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(latLng);


JSONObject destination = new JSONObject();
destination.put("destination", jsonArray);

passToJs(destination); //theoretical - method looks slightly different
```

Then, if I log what has been received in JS(lets call it 'data'), the result is the following:

```
{  
   "destination":[  
      {  
         "lat":20.000,
         "lon":20.000
      }
   ]
}
```

I am having some problem accessing the individual lat/lon values. I've tried:

```
data[0]
data[0].lat
data.lat
```

How do I read and save lat/lon to new variables? BTW, I think my JSON is not so good - is it better to just create a single JSON Object and pass that alone?

Thanks.

Comment: try `data['destination'][0].lat`

Comment: problem was with parsing - see comments on @Comforse answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `destination` node in your object. You should use `data.destination[0].lat`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that too in the past, but anyway here it is again with the error: (first line is simply data being logged as a whole)
{"destination":[{"lat":20.000,"lon":20.000}]}
navigation.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Try doing ``JSON.parse(data)`` and see if that helps. It may be that the data is seen as plaintext.

Comment: Awesome! That seemed to be the problem!! Thanks alot